# Transform data from vector to other with no default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I used to use this way to copy data with some changes from container to container:

```
std::vector<Tsrc> source{Tsrc(),Tsrc(2),Tsrc(3),Tsrc(4)};
std::vector<Tdst> dst(source.size());
std::transform(begin(source),end(source),begin(dst),[](Tsrc& item){
    return do_something(item);
}
```

First of all, is the previous code standard and clean? any enhancing may be applied?

Secondly, I now want to do the same but for a `Tdst` that does not have a default constructor. So, the above code will not work. I replaced it with:

```
std::vector<Tsrc> source{Tsrc(),Tsrc(2),Tsrc(3),Tsrc(4)};
std::vector<Tdst> dst;
dst.reserve(source.size());
for(auto& item:dst){
    dst.emplace_back(do_something(item));
}
```

Is it the right way to do it? any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing looks fine. You can avoid the explicit loop by using [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). Also, since the elements of the original range aren't being modified the lambda's parameter should be made `const`:

```
dst.reserve(source.size());
std::transform(begin(source), end(source), back_inserter(dst),
               [](const Tsrc& item){return do_something(item);});
```